# Simplified alluvial/sankey plot in R with same categories on both sides

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, ggalluvial

I would like to build a simplified alluvial/sankey plot in R that shows the same categories on both sides and only visualizes their change in size.

Probably best illustrated by [this sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS1xl.png).

How can I achieve this?

I tried the ggalluvial and the network3D package to achieve this, but always ran into the problem that I can't model a 1:1 relationship (with differently sized categories on the other side), but only m:n relationships based on the frequencies of combinations (ggalluvial) or based on the relation of how the flow should split up (network3D).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43053375/4556798) and my answer to it might address yours in the case of {ggalluvial}. Do they? Note that the solution requires the data be in "long" rather than "wide" format. In any event, a reproducible example would make your question much easier to address.